# Bootstrap table not following width with display: block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm actually running into a trouble since yesterday.
I'm using Bootstrap 4, and tables. Actually, if I put a width over 13.5vw, the table don't follow. Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/88681/
Here's the code

### HTML

```
            <table class="table table-striped datas-table table-sm rounded">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Date of Visit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Duration</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Then the CSS

### CSS

```
.datas-table {
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 0.2604166666666667vw;
    margin-left: 0.5208333333333334vw;
    height: 16.11111111111111vh;
    width: 14.583333333333334vw;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.datas-table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2), .datas-table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2) {text-align: right; padding-right: 1.1458333333333335vw;}
.datas-table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1), .datas-table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1) {padding-left: 0.5729166666666667vw;}
```

As you could see in the Fiddle, the table don't seems to follow.
The reason of why I want to use display: block, is due to overflow: auto, without it, my table won't scroll and the width will not be respected

Thankfully,

Comment: might be a better idea to wrap your table in a div with a height and overflow set instead of changing the display of the table.

Comment: When you set your table to `display:block`, the `thead`, `tbody`, and `tfoot` elements in it are wrapped in an anonymous table box (https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) which can have only default non-inherited properties. Effectively you get a `div`-like block with the given width containing a table with `width: auto` (i.e. width by content).

Comment: Thanks for your informations !
@zgood your solution solved my problem :D Thanks a lot !

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Thanks for the explanation ! It helped me to understand where my error were :)

Answer (score 0):

Try my table code,

```css
.viewTable {
        table-layout:fixed;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .thData, .tdData {
        padding:8px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .theadData, tfoot {
    background-color: #9ac9fb;
        display:table;
        width:100%;
    }
    .table-height .table .tdData {
    vertical-align: middle !important; 
    }
    .viewTable .tbodyData {
        max-height:250px;
        overflow:auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        display:block;
    width:100%;
    }
    .item-dist .tbodyData {
        height:490px;
        overflow:auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
    }



    .tbodyData .trData {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        table-layout:fixed;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff !important;
    }
    .table .theadData .thData {
    border: none !important;
    width: 10% !important;
        text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <table align="center" class="table table-hover viewTable">
            <thead class="theadData">
                <tr class="trData">
                    <th class="thData">Column 1</th>

                    <th class="thData">Column 2</th>
                    <th class="thData">Column 3</th>

                    
                    <th class="thData">Column 4</th>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
  
            <tbody class="tbodyData">
            
                  <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>                  <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>                  <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>                  <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
                                              <tr class="trData">
                    <td class="tdData">A</td>
                    <td class="tdData">B</td>
                    <td class="tdData">C</td>
                    <td class="tdData">D</td>
                    
                            </tr>
     
             
                 
            </tbody>
      </table>
```