# How to adjust width of the th as per the td width using css

Tags: html, css

I have a table using `display:block` for `thead` and `tbody`. if the data in `<td>` increases, the `<th>` also needs to increase the width but now it won't works like that....Because of `display:block` ...How to fix this? any suggestions please!

Here I have tried css:

```
table thead,table tbody {
    display: block;
}

table tbody {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: 90px;
    max-height: 300px;
}

td, th {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: will you please use fiddle or something else for code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a running example of your code via a snippet, so we can have a better look into it? You can do this by editing your post and use the `< >`-icon in the toolbar to create a snippet.

Comment: Sorry ,I don't know bro please give me a link or solution for this, with adjustable width for both td and th? If td width increase,<th> width also needs to increase it.Because of display:block it won't working.

Comment: @SPYder you are not making any effort. Sorry, but this attitude won't make others want to help you out.

Comment: @mbuechmann One second please I will give a link

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51325906/9315094] Check out this.

Comment: See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vqkht1jz/ . In this, If data(width) of `<td>` is increasing, it is increasing the width of `<th>` too. Not sure what do you want to ask. Please share your complete code.

Comment: I think what you really want is: a table with a body that has a maximum height and scrolls vertically and maximizes horizontally. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes @mbuechmann

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKVGOw

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstnamee</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
   <tobody>
  <tr>
    <td>Jon</td>
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>Watson</td> 
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>
   </tobody>
</table>


table thead,table tbody {
    display: table-header-group;
}

table tbody {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: 90px;
    max-height: 300px;
}

td, th {
  max-width: auto;
  text-align: left
}
```

Comment: display: table-header-group; I have used this already.Not working in chrome as fixed header on scroll...

Answer (score 0):

If the text is non wrapping text then you set the cell to width:1px and use white-space:nowrap. The text in that column will then determine the width of the cell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

td{width:1px;white-space:nowrap;}
table tbody {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: 90px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
      <th>Column C</th>
      <th>Column D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.1 lorem</td>
      <td>Data B.1 ip</td>
      <td>Data C.1 sum l</td>
      <td>Data D.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.2 ipsum</td>
      <td>Data B.2 lorem</td>
      <td>Data C.2 some data Data D.2 a long line of text that is longData D.2 a long line of text that is longData D.2 a long line of text that is longData D.2 a long line of text that is long</td>
      <td>Data D.2 a long line of text that is longData D.2 a long line of text that is longData D.2 a long line of text that is longData D.2 a long line of text that is long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.3</td>
      <td>Data B.3</td>
      <td>Data C.3</td>
      <td>Data D.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Scroll will added and td will adjust as per content.

Comment: This solved an issue I was having myself, thanks! (will upvote tomorrow, out of votes today)

Comment: But I need a fixed <th> how to fix this case? For this I have use Display:block..? Any other ways ? but your solution is right extra needs as fixed header <th>?

Comment: what is an issue with TH?

Comment: display block is default you don't need to write it.

Comment: I need a fixed header <th> on scrolling vertically.Your code is fine now. But How to add a fixed header with this code?

Comment: if you need vertical scroll just  change `overflow-x: hidden;` to   `overflow-x: scroll;` in style